# Expandable menu box (horizontally)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menubar

I was playing around with this idea : 
[image]

In this block I have 2 `<a>`s as buttons and an `<ul>` and tried `float`ing them to make them stick together. And the main idea to achieve this effect was manipulation width/display state of `ul` or simply the menu section.

```
<nav>
  <a class="nav-btn">Logo</a>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a class="nav-btn">Logo</a>
</nav>
```

But my main question is that **"How to make the widths to be flexible and automatic?"** No, percentages or pixels!
The main section(grey background) should expand/and collapse automatically and take as much space as needed based on its content. And when the menu is toggled off and hypothetically we set the width of "Menu" to zero, the background should adjust and those two buttons should be like the picture.

What structure or html do you suggest?

Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the html structure as is. you will have set the following css properties to get the basic layout set up:

```
a, li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

than you can toggle the display property of the <ul> via javascript. see: [js FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9wfemwx0/1/)

you can also use the nav's hover state to toggle the li's visibility via css

```
ul {
    display: none;
}

nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

see: [css FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xj3hj7x8/)

if the logo's are not links you might want to use div's instead of a's.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It was helpful. But what about the whole "responsive" idea? Don't you think setting a solid 100px is against this idea? Do you have any suggestions to make it as flexible and responsive as possible?

Comment: the 100px was just an example. you can set whatever size you want

Comment: I mean shouldn't it be as wide as the words and letters? 100px is kinda static!

Comment: it's an example. please read your previous comment and my response to it. you do not have to define a size at all and can use `auto` or whatever you like instead.